# Is Smith's book still usable and up-to-date?

Tags: reference-request

I'm learning DSP with [Smith's book](http://www.dspguide.com/), but I discovered the second edition is from 1999, is this book still usable today?

Answer (score 3):

Do you think that there are a lot of new things have been introduced in the last 10 years? :-)

I like this book. Book is quite accurate and quite pragmatic.  I think this book is a great introduction to DSP. But feel free  to use another books, especially if you want to known about the modern hardware equipment.

Comment: That was one of my doubts, I didn't know if something had changed.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, I have it at home as well, but I put it down and got Richard Lyons' book instead. Richard Lyons' book is, hands down, ̶o̶n̶e̶ ̶o̶f̶  the best DSP books I have ever seen.

Smiths' book is still ok in my book, no pun intended. In a field as wide as this, diversity is key, hearing the same content be talked about by different authors really helps build a more solid understanding of it. Some new nuggets are also presented, but you also get the authors' unique experience leak through, which is valuable in and of itself.

Answer (score 2):

Smith's book is geared more towards practicioners than academics.  So the emphasis is more on the ideas of DSP than on the sometimes abstract and arcane mathematics that DSP requires.  For this reason I found Smith's book to be a much better learning aid than the more formal textbooks.  For the basic principles of DSP not all that much has changed in the past decade or so so 1999 is not out of date.